# wpf render transform animation, wrong data trigger fired

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, datatrigger

```
<Style x:Key="ScaleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsShowing}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0.5" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" />
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0.5" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsShowing}" Value="False">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Now it always starts the second data trigger, while it should start the first one , because the actual value of IsShowing is True, untill i press close button, so i dont know why this is ignoring that value and it always fires the second datatrigger.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: First thing to check is if your binding is actually working. And if it is could IsShowing ever be false when the control is loaded. Because the if your second trigger is being hit it means that the property  IsShowing that your control is bound to is false.

Comment: The binding is working if i leave only the first data trigger then, it works when i open it, but when i add the second one it ignores the first one :(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating another trigger, put other Storyboard in **`DataTrigger.ExitActions`** and it will work fine.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsShowing}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation From="0.5" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" />
                <DoubleAnimation From="0.5" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.1" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"/>
                <DoubleAnimation To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.1" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however i tried it and when i click the button the IsShowing property is setup to false and close immediately and no animation is done :( is there anyway to make the animation apear first before the window closes ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <Style x:Key="ScaleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">           
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsShowing,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsShowing,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.1" ScaleY="0.1" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>           
  </Style>
```

Comment: I tried it, and it doesnt work, and i also get this:System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsShowing' property not found on 'object' ''Grid' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=IsShowing; DataItem='Grid' (Name=''); target element is 'Grid' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
So it doesnt find the property its being bound to. But thank you for the suggestion :) any other ideas please?

Comment: Well i tested your code using togglebutton http://prntscr.com/36kcge and it is working for me.and your error is showing problem to targetname.so try by putting <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsShowing,ElementName=ScaleStyle}" Value="True">